# Loop though all input boxes and clear them

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I, using javascript, loop through all input boxes on a page and clear the data inside of them (making them all blank)?

Comment: Which part don't you know how to do? Select them, iterate the collection, or clear them? In other words, what have you tried?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this code:

```
​$('input').val('');
```

It's looping over all `input` elements and it's setting their value to the empty string.
Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maqVn/1/

And of course if you don't have jQuery:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
    inputs[i].value = '';
}​​​​
```

Since I prefer the functional style, you can use:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.getElementsByTagName('input'))
  .forEach(function (el) {
    el.value = '';
});
```

Comment: How do you know jQuery is loaded?

Comment: if jQuery is allowed: `$('input').val('');​` would be enough.

Answer (score 10):

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), function(e){
  e.value = '';
});
```

**Edit:** If you want to grab textareas and other elements, you can use `querySelectorAll`:

```
[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea'), 
  function(e) { e.value = ''; }
);
```

Comment: Best answer by far.

Answer (score 3):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), 
    clearTypes = { "text" : 1, "password" : 1, "email" : 1 }, // etc. you fill this in
    i = inputs.length, 
    input;

while (i) {
    if (clearTypes[(input = inputs[--i]).type]) {
        input.value = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jquery:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  if(list[i].type == 'text' || list[i].type == 'password')
    list[i].value = '';
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for-in` for this. It includes more than just the numeric indices in the iteration.

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more? What do you mean by 'more than numeric indices'? Could you give me an example? That's the way I usually solve such problems but I would be happy if you show me a better way.

Comment: JavaScript's for-in is a general enumerator. It will include every enumerable property on the object, whether directly on the object, or inherited. When used on an Array object, it doesn't limit itself to just the numeric indices. It also doesn't guarantee a particular order of enumeration. If you do `console.log(i);` in your loop in FireFox, you'll get the indices, but then also `length`, `item` and `namedItem`. It's better to do an iteration that is constrained by your code to only include the numeric indices. A standard `for` loop is the typical way. `for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {`

Comment: Thank you! I will fix that and think of it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just to register an alternative without JavaScript, the HTML element `<input type="reset" />` clear all fields of the `form`. In some scenarios it may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do something like tha following:

```
<script>   
 e = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    if (e[i].type != 'text') continue;

    e[i].value = '';
    }
</script>
```

**Edited: added exclude for input which their types are not text!**