# Empty / blank out all fields in a form page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have the below code, is there a way to put this in a simpler format.
I am having to blank out 50 or more fields when a date in a certain key field is changed or made blank.

```
if (zEntry ==""){

document.getElementById("Q229I1226").value="";
document.getElementById("DQ230I1227").value="";
document.getElementById("DQ231I1228").value="";
document.getElementById("Q4I1001").value="";

//Date from fall to arrival 
document.getElementById("Q232I1229").value="";
document.getElementById("DQ233I1230").value="";
document.getElementById("DQ234I1231").value="";
document.getElementById("Q5I1002").value="";

//Date Time of referral to T&O surgery
document.getElementById("Q238I1235").value="";
document.getElementById("DQ239I1236").value="";
document.getElementById("DQ240I1237").value="";
document.getElementById("Q15I1012").value="";
document.getElementById("Q17I1014").value="";       

//Date seen T&O 1st on call
document.getElementById("Q241I1238").value="";
document.getElementById("DQ242I1239").value="";
document.getElementById("DQ243I1240").value="";
document.getElementById("Q16I1013").value="";
}
```

Thank you

Comment: add class to the fields and try `document.getElementsByClassName('example').value ='';`

Comment: will I be able to do the same even if the key field value is changed? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add common class to your inputs.

```
var array = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
for (var i = 0, lng = array.length; i < lng; i++) {
    array[i].value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear out all fields with same tag you can just use

`document.getElementsByTagName(arg)` while arg being 'input', 'option' etc.

But if you want specific inputs to be cleared, you have to give them a class and use

```
document.getElementsByClassName(arg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to the input fields and try

`var array_container = document.getElementsByClassName('example');
 for (var i = 0, i < array_container.length; i++) {
     array_container[i].value = '';
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach too:

```
// store all the element ids in an array
var element_ids = ['Q229I1226', 'DQ230I1227', 'DQ231I1228', 'Q4I1001',
                   'Q232I1229'];

element_ids.forEach(function(element_id){
     document.getElementById(element_id).value = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution of how to clear all input boxes/fields by looping.

[Loop though all input boxes and clear them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435231/loop-though-all-input-boxes-and-clear-them)